# Lotus Notes on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, lotus-notes

I thought id ask this here instead of superuser, as lotus notes is a bit more enterprisy.

I have a thinkpad t61 with ubuntu 9.04 installed and Lotus Notes 8.5. Normally the system performance is fine/great, running at about 10% cpu usage with Firefox and some terminals open, and lotus notes not doing anything.

As soon as i try to do anything in lotus notes (ie open the calendar or open an email) the CPU usage jumps up to like 60-70% utilisation, with 50% of that notes. it doesnt use a lot of ram either. Just sits there using heaps of CPU% which slows down everything else. after a couple of minutes, it works its way out of this and everything returns to normal, until I try to do something again. where it does it again.

Any Ideas?

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lotus notes taking 50% cpu sounds like 100% of a single core.  If your machine is a dualcore, or dual cpu machine -- look at the numerous complaints regarding Ubuntu and Notes consuming an entire core [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=linux+lotus+notes+cpu&aq=f&aqi=&fp=8ec80112f99bfde5).

[This post](http://www.benkevan.com/blog/ubuntu-new-wave-theme-caused-100-cpu-with-lotus-notes-eclipse/) seems to suggest it is a theme issue.

Comment: Bang on. I had the "new wave" theme enabled. Switched back to the default. All good now.

Comment: Lovely Eclipse bug....

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the same network as the Notes server or are you remote? I've no experience with Notes in these situations, but I'm a remote employee and I've noticed some odd behavior with Exchange and some other items that seems to be related to me being remote (hardware VPN) from the servers.

I'd also look at your AV software - The stuff my company gives me has it's own set of issues with remote people, because it likes to talk to the server quite often, and it can chew up a lot of CPU for some reason when it's waiting for responses.

Have you talked to the Notes Admins about this? Also, is there any way you can justify a dual CPU system? I've found that having a second CPU helps quite a bit with bad apps, by allowing me to continue mostly unhindered while some app sucks up CPU.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Im on the same network as the domino server, so i dont think thats the issue. I dont think I have an AV software, though i'll look into it.As the CPU is comeing from the Notes Process i dont think its that tho. The T61 is a dual core cpu. I havnt talked to the notes admins, as they are mostly concerned with windows. But thank you for the advice!